# Using python to download a file after clicking the generate icon

Tags: python, download, popupwindow

I am working on a project. Each day I need to login to a website. Navigate to a report page. After entering the require information, and clicking on the "gererate report" icon, there's a pop up windown asking me to save the file. I want to do it automatically by python.

I search the internet for a couple of days, and now I can do it by Autoit, but can't find a way in python. 
By using urllib2, I can process up to clicking the "generate report" icon. But how can I get the name and location of the file and download it?

I want to make clear that the "generate report" button is actuary the submit button of a form. There is no Href associate with the generate button. After submitting the form, a file-save dialog popup asking me where to save the file.

thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of popup opens? Javascript or the File-Save dialog from the browser?

Comment: file-save dialog from firefox

Comment: It's almost a year, I still can't find a way to do it. However, I am satisfy using a autoit script to download the file. As long as I do not switch to another computer, I am good!

Comment: We would need more information e.g. a copy of that website. Ever tried mechanize or the python requests library?

Comment: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-auto-save-files-using-custom-firefox-profile

Answer (score 1):

If it's a save file dialog from Fx it probably means that it directly links to a file. If you manage to fill all the information and click the generate_report icon, can't you check which href has the generate_button assigned to it?

```
import urlib
urlfile = "Href of the generate_button"
urllib.urlretrieve(urlfile,"filename")
```

Comment: Hi user1473351 Thanks for the answer. There is no Href of the generate button. This is a form, the generate button is actually the "submit" button. After submitting the form, a file-save dialog popup asking me where to save the file.

Comment: Just use the **urllib.urlretrieve(urlfile,"filename")** here filename will be the exact path with the extension of the file and the file is saved :)